# Random lag on connection

Tags: http, measure

when i try to connect to my friend's server, the connection seems randomly laggy, sometimes it's 50ms, 40ms, 60ms, but sometimes it tooks 1, 3 or 7 seconds

```
time curl -vv 'http://ipaddress/foo.json'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ipaddress... --> SLOW AT THIS LINE !!!
* Connected to ipaddress (ipaddress) port 80 (#0)
> GET /foo.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: ipaddress
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 02:51:45 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
< Last-Modified: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 02:42:12 GMT
< ETag: "2e8109e-871-4fc8be82affe4"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 2161
< Content-Type: application/json
```

How could I know which part of the system that causes this?

I've tried to disable mod_bwlimited, but the lag still happened

I've tried to use another web server (monkey) on another port, it still happened

the server:

```
Linux bar 2.6.32-042stab090.3 #1 SMP Fri Jun 6 09:35:21 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also when I tried to change `/etc/sysctl.conf` and using `sysctl -p` using `root`:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
fs.file-max = 524288
```

It shows:

```
error: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle'
error: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse'
error: permission denied on key 'fs.file-max'
```

Maybe that values was restricted by the hosting company?

Comment: When you're lagging, use [mtr](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mtr) to check the connection to the server.

Comment: the `mtr` shows average 23ms to server, worst at 179ms

Comment: That's normal.  You want to look for any links with a high `Loss%` or `Avg`.  This is an easy way to rule out the connection between two endpoints.

Comment: Loss is 0.0% and Avg stil the same around 21ms

Comment: ah, just now, the Wrst is 7722ms on last host, maybe it's really about the network problem

Comment: yea, that's a 7.7 second delay...

Comment: I seem to experience similar issues. @Kokizzu were you ever able to find the root cause of this lag ?

Comment: no, i don't even remember which friend's server that has this problem '___')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're lagging, use `mtr` to check the connection to the server.

`mtr` is a traceroute program on steroids.  It runs a continuous `traceroute` and generates meaningful network statistics such as % of lost packets and several RTT metrics.

Statistics are generated for each link between you and the selected endpoint.  Any links that exhibit a high `Loss%` or `Avg` may be a source of network issues for your connection.